# Where to find the `scene` in React Navigation's navigationOptions?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to implement a custom back button in a React Navigation `StackNavigator` `Header`.

This works:

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
  return {
    title: '...',
    headerStyle: {
      ...
    },
    headerTitleStyle: {
      ...
    },
    headerLeft: <BackButton onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}/>,
  }
};
```

But now I want to hide the back button when there's nowhere to go back to. I found that the [default header does this](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/master/src/views/Header/Header.js#L124) by looking at the current scene's index, and hiding it if the index === 0.

But is the `scenes` stack supplied to `navigationOptions`? If it is, where is it? Or is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of doing this:

1. hold the navigation stack info in state management (I think you can easily find tutorials at least for Redux and MobX)
2. `navigation` holds object `state` which has information about routes. If `routeName` matches with your initial route, then it's obvious that you're on first scene.

If either of these matches, then you can just set `headerLeft` to *null*.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by using `withNavigation` in the `BackButton` component itself. This seems to give me information not present on the `navigation` object passed passed to `navigationOptions`.

```
import { withNavigation } from 'react-navigation';

export default withNavigation(({onPress, navigation}) => {
  if(navigation.state.index === 0) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity 
    ...
```